# ActiveMQ network of brokers with durable subscription topics

Tags: activemq-classic, failover, broker, subscriber

I have a little problem here with my sample JMS layout.

I have two brokers (A, B) on two machines, which are linked via network connector. The idea is that the producer can send to any broker and the consumer can listen to any broker and the topic to send to/receive from is available globally.

The topic has two durable subscriber clients (one on each machine) that both will process all the messages in the topic. I want it to be a durable subscription so that the processes won't loose any workload if a process has to be restarted. Both subscriber clients are configured to have a failover broker url, so that they first try to connect to their localhost broker and if not available to the other. Failover of the clients seems to work, but I found a problem in the following situation:

Each broker 'A' and 'B' have a subscriber client connected The producer is sending to 'A'. Broker 'B' gets restarted. Client of 'B' registers connection loss and switches to 'A'. 'B' comes up again, and because it had itself registered as a durable subscriber to 'A' it gets the message feed. It has no active durable subscriber now ('A' has now three, including 'B') and piles up until it reaches its connection limits.

Is my configuration wrong? Is it possible what I've intended?

Cheers,
Kai

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you running master-slave configuration?
2. Why do you want both brokers to have connected clients at the same time?

If you user failover connection string (identifying both brokers in it) your consumers/producers will use ActiveMQ failover implementation and will connect/reconnect to the active node when needed. I don't think having two active instances with active clients is a good idea - unless you are trying to duplicate your processes (in this case there will be no synchronization)

To make both nodes (master and slave) to always have the same durable data you need
to persist your messages to the same place accessible to both nodes. It can be JDBC adapter connected to a single instance of database (probably behind the cluster) or it can be NAS with shared network folder for KahaDB.

Comment: It is not master-slave but a (http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) network of brokers with static discovery. The infrastructure demand is that we have consumers and high traffic producers on the same box. If the broker fails the producers should be allowed to connect to the other broker as an exception over the net (is there a way to reconnect them automatically to the original if it comes back?), and the consumers of course should do the same. Then there are clients that should connect to any network broker and receive topic messages from producers from both brokers.

Comment: to make the picture more clear, we have two computers with each some producers and a consumer here, that also produces messages at lower rate and with less payload to end clients on remote machines. If one of the computers fails the end clients should easily switch to the other broker and still have most of the functionality.